# Getting net.rcarz.jiraclient.RestException: 400 for multiselect custom field in Jira

Tags: selenium, testng, jira-rest-java-api

I am unable to create ticket when passing details of custom field. getting 400 bad request with message as mentioned below :
**net.rcarz.jiraclient.RestException: 400 : {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"Customer":"expected Object"}}**

Field Details:

```
customfield_1003={"required":true,"schema":{"type":"array","items":"option","custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multiselect","customId":1003},"name":"Customer","fieldId":"customfield_1003","hasDefaultValue":false,"operations":["add","set","remove"],"allowedValues":[{"self":""}]}
```

Tried multiple ways as bellow but no luck:

1.

```
            FluentCreate newIssueFluentCreate = jira.createIssue(project, issueType);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.SUMMARY, summary);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field("customfield_1003", new ArrayList<Object>() {{add(customer);}});
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.DESCRIPTION, description);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.LABELS, new ArrayList<Object>() {{add(label);}});
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.PRIORITY, "Minor");
            newIssue = newIssueFluentCreate.execute();
```

2. 

```
            JSONObject customerObject = new JSONObject();
            customerObject.put("value", "1225");            
            ArrayList<Object> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            customers.add(customerObject);
            
            FluentCreate newIssueFluentCreate = jira.createIssue(project, issueType);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.SUMMARY, summary);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field("customfield_1003", customers);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.DESCRIPTION, description);
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.LABELS, new ArrayList<Object>() {{add(label);}});
            newIssueFluentCreate.field(Field.PRIORITY, "Minor");
            newIssue = newIssueFluentCreate.execute();
```

HTML for this field :

```
<div class="field-group">
   <label for="customfield_1003">Customer<span class="aui-icon icon-required">Required</span></label>
  <select class="select cf-select" id="customfield_1003" multiple="multiple" name="customfield_1003" size="5" data-remove-null-options="true" data-submit-input-val="true" data-input-text="">
            <option value="12306">Text1</option>
            <option value="10615">Text2</option>
            <option value="10329">Text3</option>
            <option value="1225">All</option>
            <option value="11014">Text4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about this lib but I observed one mismatch here:

```
customerObject.put("value", "1225");
```

vs

```
<option value="12245">All</option>
```

and I guess you can try this.

```
newIssueFluentCreate.field("customfield_1003", Arrays.asList("12306", "10615"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment , that values is not matter i have updated them while posting with some dummy values and updated the post as well but Arrays.asList() is also not the solution because at the end both are creating a ArrayList only which is not helping here. :(